# Como obter o número de colunas de uma tabela temporária

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como é possível obter o número de colunas existentes em uma determinada tabela temporária no *sql server*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Experimente usar o [seguinte SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1465014/2387977):

```
SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = 'database' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'sua_tabela'
```

Para tabelas temporárias, [use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18761227/2387977):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tempdb.sys.columns
WHERE object_id = object_id('tempdb..#tmp_grid_email')
```

Comment: Não funcionou :/

Comment: create table #tmp_grid_email (
 id int primary key,
 nome nvarchar(30),
 endereco nvarchar(50)
)

Comment: usando esta tabela para teste e retornou zero no lugar de 3

Comment: O problema é que se trata de uma tabela temporária

Comment: Funcinou valeuuuuuu

Answer (score 1):

Olá, 
veja se o código abaixo atende a sua necessidade.

```
-- ==============================
-- exibindo qtd de colunas
-- ==============================

SELECT COUNT(*) AS QTD
FROM 
    sys.sysobjects    AS T (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN sys.all_columns AS C (NOLOCK) ON T.id = C.object_id AND T.XTYPE = 'U' 
WHERE 
    T.NAME LIKE '%NOME_TABELA%'

-- ==============================
-- exibindo as colunas
-- ==============================

SELECT 
    T.name AS Tabela, 
    C.name AS Coluna
FROM 
    sys.sysobjects    AS T (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN sys.all_columns AS C (NOLOCK) ON T.id = C.object_id AND T.XTYPE = 'U' 
WHERE 
    T.NAME LIKE '%NOME_TABELA%'
ORDER BY 
    C.column_id ASC
```